# How to Create Dynamic UI With String ID in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-layout, textview

I develop android application that in my application all layouts and widgets are created dynamically.
All data will be received from a JSON file and all ids for elements are also in the same file.
for example I want use this

```
String id=txt_site_id   
TextView txt = new TextView(this);
txt.setID(id);
```

but it's can't work because setid just use int value for create dynamic id

Now,How I can Resolve my Problems

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thing came into my mind was using a Tag:

```
txt.setTag(id);
(...)
txt.getTag(id);
```

If this isn't enough, please provide more input, what you try to achieve.

Comment: I had use random id number.for example init=6000; in for increamet init then put in hashmap for save in temp

Comment: Please provide more input what you try to do with your Ids.